cpulimit is not resuming the process back
I have a script that uploads data to a remote location, in order for this script to not consume too many resources on the VM, I have set cpulimit for the upload process. however all of a sudden I see on some VMs the process is paused by the cpulimit but it is never resume/continued back. Is there a way to identify what's causing this problem?
This problem was never seen when using Centos7 but see it all of a sudden when migrating to rocky8.
The process is started with cpulimit -l 15
